# Why does F3 not work as Find Next in Chrome?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, shortcut

I've already set up in system preferences, checkbox Use all F1, F2,... as standard function (checked on).

But still after  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>   on Chrome, pressing  <kbd>F3</kbd>   won't do anything... I expected Find Next would go.... only way is pressing  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>

any chance?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>F3</kbd>, like the previous poster said, is a Windows convention.  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is how all applications within OS X do a "Find".  However, you can re-map your Windows favorites to OS X with no problem.

If you want to make <kbd>F3</kbd> = "Find Next" in Google Chrome, you can set that up yourself.

Go to [System Preferences] --> [Keyboard] --> [Shortcuts]

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Select App Shortcuts and then click the "plus sign" to add a new one.  You will get a dialog box like the one below

[image]

Select your Application that you want to create the shortcut for, in this case Google Chrome.

Now, here is the most important part:  Type the name of the menu command **exactly** as you see it.  Go to the menu bar at the top of the screen and select the command from one of the menu drop downs.  In this case, it's "Find Next"

[image]

Enter that into your new Shortcut and assign the key you want, in this case <kbd>F3</kbd>.  It should look like this:

[image]

Click "Add" and you should see it show up as an new Shortcut.  Head over to Chrome and you will see that "Find Next" is now mapped to <kbd>F3</kbd>

Comment: In the current version of Chrome, command is called `Find next`, not `Find Next`

Comment: In the _now_ current version of Chrome (105.0.5195.125), the commands that worked for me are Find Next / Find Previous as per the answer.

Answer (score 1):

F3 for search is very much a Windows shortcut, & in fact isn't in the shortcuts list for Google Chrome on Mac at all.

[image]

[image]

Source : [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB)